# Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'ObjectLiteral'

Tags: typescript, express, typeorm, typescript-generics

i want to implement the generic repository/service pattern in this way

```
import { EntityTarget, FindOptionsWhere } from "typeorm";

import { AppDataSource as db } from "../database";

export const getAllSerivce  = async <T>(
  entity: EntityTarget<T>,
  query?: FindOptionsWhere<T>
) => {
  const repository = db.getRepository(entity);
  const res = query ? await repository.findBy(query) : await repository.find();
  return res;
};
```

but i got this error :

> Argument of type 'EntityTarget' is not assignable to parameter of
> type 'EntityTarget'.   Type '{ type: T; name: string;
> }' is not assignable to type 'EntityTarget'.
> Type '{ type: T; name: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ type: ObjectLiteral; name: string; }'.
> Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
> Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'ObjectLiteral'.ts(2345) generic.service.ts(5, 38): This type parameter might need an `extends ObjectLiteral` constraint.

Comment: Have you tried doing what the error message suggests? `async <T extends ObjectLiteral>(...) => ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `EntityTarget` or `FindOptionsWhere` have a generic constraint on `T`, you need to add that constraint to your function as well:

```
export const getAllSerivce  = async <T extends ObjectLiteral>(
//                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  entity: EntityTarget<T>,
  query?: FindOptionsWhere<T>
) => {
  const repository = db.getRepository(entity);
  const res = query ? await repository.findBy(query) : await repository.find();
  return res;
};
```